# Use greater than operator in like operator Hive

Tags: sql, hiveql, rdbms

I want to use numerical greater than operator in like clause in hive sql.

```
select col1,col2 
from table_1
where NOT (col_3 RLIKE 'p=2')
```

**instead of 'p=2' i want to eliminate all the values where p>2
How can i achieve that?**

Any leads would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking, preferably with some sample data. If you had a column called 'p' and wanted all records where p>2 that would make sense to me but I'm unclear what p>2 means within another column